# Why "Convention" for Moderators?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering why the Convention badge was a pre-req for being a moderator.  The other three make considerable sense to me, the connection with this one less so.  And, it would certainly appear to be the #1 gate-keeper as it has been awarded far fewer times than the other three.

If there is an existing discussion of this that my search skills weren't up to the task of finding, I'd be thankful for a pointer.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know how many people who are actually interested in nominating don't have Convention. It's near impossible to get hard numbers on that, though.

Comment: An interesting point to be sure, but I suppose as long as there are sufficient good candidates each election, it's purely academic.

Comment: Looking back at the badge’s history, there’s been at least one elected moderator (Jon) to pick it up specifically in order to make a nomination.

Comment: It was hidden over on MSE; I've relocated it - thanks for asking!